# Parse Error in some phones

Tags: android, parse-error

I have created a simple app which works fine on my phone with 4.2.1. It works on one of my friends phone too which runs icecream sandwich. But when I tested on my another friends phone(note 2) which runs 4.1.1 its not even getting installed. What am I doing wrong.

My XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/orange" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
     android:text="TECHNICAL\nENGLISH -I"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
     android:text="ENGINEERING\nPHYSICS I"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
     android:text="ENGINEERING\nCHEMISTRY I"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView5"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
     android:text="COMPTER\nPROGRAMMING"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView6"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
     android:text="ENGINEERING\nGRAPHICS"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView7"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="445dp"
     android:text="COMPUTER\nPRGRAMMING LAB"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView8"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
     android:text="ENGINEERING\nPRACTICES LAB"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView9"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="575dp"
     android:text="PHYSICS\nCHEMISTRY LAB"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner5"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner6"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner7"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="435dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner8"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner9"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="565dp"
     android:entries="@array/Grade"
     android:prompt="@string/hello_world"
     android:text="Medium Text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <Space
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView11"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="SEMESTER I - GPA CALCULATOR"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="20dp" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
     android:text="MATHEMATICS - I"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
     android:text="calculate" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/editText1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
     android:editable="false"
     android:ems="10"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gpa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cgpa.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Main_Activity file:

```
    package com.example.cgpa;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    import com.example.gpa.R;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView e1;
    int g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, cr = 0;
    int co1 = 0, co2 = 0, co3 = 0, co4 = 0, co5 = 0, co6 = 0, co7 = 0, co8 = 0,
            co9 = 0;
    String an, ch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        final Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        final Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        final Spinner spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        final Spinner spinner6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
        final Spinner spinner7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
        final Spinner spinner8 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
        final Spinner spinner9 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner9);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        e1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 10;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("A".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 9;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("B".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 8;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("C".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 7;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("D".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 6;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("E".equals(i1)) {
                    g1 = 5;
                    co1++;
                    if (co1 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("U".equals(i1)) {
                    if (co1 >=1) {
                        cr = cr - 4;
                        co1 = 0;
                    }
                    g1 = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 10;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("A".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 9;

                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("B".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 8;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("C".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 7;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("D".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 6;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("E".equals(i2)) {
                    g2 = 5;
                    co2++;
                    if (co2 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("U".equals(i2)) {
                    if (co2 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 4;
                        co2 = 0;
                    }
                    g2 = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 10;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("A".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 9;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("B".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 8;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("C".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 7;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("D".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 6;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("E".equals(i3)) {
                    g3 = 5;
                    co3++;
                    if (co3 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("U".equals(i3)) {
                    if (co3 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 3;
                        co3 = 0;
                    }
                    g3 = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i4 = spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 10;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("A".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 9;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("B".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 8;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("C".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 7;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("D".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 6;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("E".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 5;
                    co4++;
                    if (co4 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("U".equals(i4)) {
                    g4 = 0;

                    if (co4 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 3;
                        co4 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i5 = spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 10;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("A".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 9;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("B".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 8;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("C".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 7;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("D".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 6;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;
                } else if ("E".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 5;
                    co5++;
                    if (co5 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 3;

                } else if ("U".equals(i5)) {
                    g5 = 0;
                    if (co5 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 3;
                        co5 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner6.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i6 = spinner6.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 10;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("A".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 9;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("B".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 8;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("C".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 7;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("D".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 6;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;
                } else if ("E".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 5;
                    co6++;
                    if (co6 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 4;

                } else if ("U".equals(i6)) {
                    g6 = 0;
                    if (co6 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 4;
                        co6 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner7.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i7 = spinner7.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 10;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("A".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 9;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("B".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 8;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("C".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 7;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("D".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 6;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("E".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 5;
                    co7++;
                    if (co7 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("U".equals(i7)) {
                    g7 = 0;
                    if (co7 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 2;
                        co7 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner8.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i8 = spinner8.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 10;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("A".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 9;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("B".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 8;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("C".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 7;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("D".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 6;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;
                } else if ("E".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 5;
                    co8++;
                    if (co8 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 2;

                } else if ("U".equals(i8)) {
                    g8 = 0;
                    if (co8 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 2;
                        co8 = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        spinner9.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String i9 = spinner9.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if ("S".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 10;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;

                } else if ("A".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 9;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;

                } else if ("B".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 8;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;
                } else if ("C".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 7;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;
                } else if ("D".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 6;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;
                } else if ("E".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 5;
                    co9++;
                    if (co9 == 1)
                        cr = cr + 1;

                } else if ("U".equals(i9)) {
                    g9 = 0;
                    if (co9 >= 1) {
                        cr = cr - 1;
                        co9 = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int a = (g1 * 4 + g2 * 4 + g3 * 3 + g4 * 3 + g5 * 3 + g6 *4
                        + g7 * 2 + g8 * 2 + g9 * 1);

                double e11 = a / (float) cr;
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                an = df.format(e11);
                ch = String.valueOf(an);
                e1.setText("Your GPA is " + ch);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

Comment: "It's not even getting installed" - please be more explicit about this, it's not clear what happens. And there's no been no mention of "Parse error" in question's description, where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its working I had send him a dropbox link and he dowloaded the link page instead of the apk.